# Referencing value stored in dcc.Store() to use for further data transformations

Tags: python

Suppose I have a dataframe that I import into page_1 of a multipage dash app.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'color':['green', 'green', 'blue', 'red'], 'amount':[1,2,4,4]})
```

I also have a value `stored_color` that the user can select in page_2, which is stored using `dcc.Store('stored_color')` in my app.py file. I can also successfully display this `stored_color` in page_1 using, for example, `html.Div()`. No problems there.

What I need to do is filter `df` in page_1 using the `stored_color` from page_2, and use this filtered_df to generate a dropDown list for the user in page_1.

Naively, I thought something like

```
filtered_df = df[df['color'] == dcc.Store('stored_color')['value']]
```

would do the trick, but of course this doesn't work, because I cannot access the values of dcc.Store() directly. I've tried using a callback, but it seems the callback functions only create outputs that are intended for displaying in the app, whereas I really need an output that can be used for further transformations/filtering. Is it possible to embed the filter within a callback that also generates the dropdown?

Any guidance here would be much appreciated!